# Reason for returning true in isCancelled() in ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice

`isCancelled()` gives me `true` flag while executing `callable()` using `.invokeAll()` method in `ExecutorService`. If i try to use `.submit()` gives me `false` otherwise. What is the for getting true while using `invokeAll()` method?

```
ExecutorService executorService = 
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Set<Callable<String>> callables = new. 
HashSet<Callable<String>>();

callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        executeCommand();
    return "Task 1";
 }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
     public String call() throws Exception {
         executeCommand();
    return "Task 2";
 }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
         executeCommand();
    return "Task 3";
}
});

List<Future<String>> futures = 
executorService.invokeAll(callables);

for(Future<String> future : futures){
    System.out.println(future.isCancelled());
    System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
}

executorService.shutdown();
```

Consider the above example where executeCommand() which has some logic to execute the code parallel which is wrapped around jobs. I get true using isCancelled() method. Using ExecutorService.submit() , it gives false.

Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a minimal code sample that demonstrates this behaviour.

Comment: it will be better if you add the code

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that is explained in the proper [`ExecutorService` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

- `invokeAll`: Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures **holding their status and results when all complete or timeout expires, whichever happens first.**
- `submit`: Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future **representing the pending result of the task.**